# PrimeNG Table Angular 6 row grouping with checkbox

Tags: angular6, primeng

I'm creating a Table in angular 6 with row-grouping and row-checkbox feature using PrimeNG Table, but when I select all individual row of a row-group then the row-group is not getting selected automatically and same issue coming for table header checkbox . Has anyone implemented the same functionality or is there any reference for the same?

My Requirement is:

1)  when I select table header checkbox all the checkbox inside table should be selected
2)  When I  select row-group checkbox all rows checkbox of that particular group should be selected
3)  When all the rows inside table are selected then table header checkbox should be automatically selected(if table header checkbox was not selected previously)
4) If I select all row checkbox of  particular row group then row header checkbox should be automatically selected(if it was not selected previously)
5) data should be properly reflected for selected row.

Code sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xory1u

Comment: Share your sample code.

Comment: As per your code. If I click on Group 0 , all the child 'myName1', 'myName2', 'myName8' all are getting selected. So now What is your requirement ?